# How to redirect url in httpd

Tags: apache

In my Apache server I need to redirect my URL https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-6 to https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-7

How do I redirect to accomplish this ?

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. See also [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteRule    "^/ulsoor-6$"  "/ulsoor-7" [PT]
```

try this.

Comment: Will it take time to effect RewriteRule??

Comment: try to replace  with full url

Comment: You can also redirect in .htaccess file

Comment: in .htaccess file you can write this, Redirect  https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-6   https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-7

Comment: you can tell what you trying to do,

Comment: https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-6 . Here ulsoor-6 has changed to ulsoor-7 so if some try to hit the url with ulsoor-6 then it should redirect to  https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-7

Comment: Write this line at the top of file  or before returning any thing to browser header("Location:http://www.test.example.com/service- 
     apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-7");

Comment: I did it using regex using RewriteRule command. It's work now.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule .*ulsoor-6   https://test.example.com/service-apartment/Bangalore/ulsoor-7  [R,L]